# How to get full path of a named pipe

Tags: visual-c++, named-pipes

how can I get the full path of a named-pipe after creating it by CreateNamedPipe function in Visual C++?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the API [NtQueryDirectoryFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), see [here](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/295120) for sample code and discussion.